# browser-sync does not refresh the page from gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, browser-sync, gulp-watch, gulp-browser-sync

`browser-sync` used with `gulp` does not refresh the page in the browser even for a simple setup.

Versions: `gulp`: 4.0.2, `browser-sync`: 2.26.7, `Chrome`: 81.0.4044.138

Folder structure:

```
|- src/
    |- index.html
|- dist
```

`gulpfile.js`:

```js
const { task, src, dest, series, watch } = require('gulp');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

task('html', () => {
    return src('src/*.html').pipe(dest('dist'));
});

task('browserSync', () => {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'dist'
        }
    });
});

task(
    'watch',
    series(
        task('html'),
        (done) => {
            watch('src/*.html', task('html'));
            watch('dest/*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);
            done();
        },
        task('browserSync')
    )
);
```

When I run `gulp watch`, `src/index.html` is successfully copied to `dest/index.html`, and `browser-sync` is started (Chrome opens the page and shows me *"Browsersync connected"*).

When I make any changes in `src/index.html`, it is copied to `dest/index.html` but `browser-sync` doesn't refresh the page.

I tried replacing `browserSync.reload` with `() => console.log('reloaded')` inside `watch('dist/*.html').on('change', ...)` call, and the log message is shown successfully every time I change `src/index.html` file (which means that the watcher works properly and `browserSync.reload` is called). Also tried restarting Chrome.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

---

Update: it starts working if I put `watch('dist/*.html', browserSync.reload);` inside the `browserSync` task (which is strange):

```js
task('browserSync', () => {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'dist'
        }
    });

    watch('dist/*.html', browserSync.reload);
});
```

Another option that helps is adding `files` property to make `browser-sync` create its own file watcher:

```js
task('browserSync', () => {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'dist'
        },
        files: [ 'dist/*.html' ]
    });
});
```

Comment: You're going to be mad ;>}  You are watching `watch('dest/*.html')` but moving the `html` file to `dist`.

Comment: @Mark you saved my day! Thanks!